# "MySQL returned an empty result set

Tags: mysql, join, random

I have a table (table1) that I store some people. I need to select random, one by one and add to another table (table2). If a person it's added, that person can be selected one more time until all the people are selected. This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM people inner join people_generated on people.id = people_generated.id WHERE people.id != people_generated.id_people ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

The second table "people_generated" is empty so, remain people to generate. Why result is empty?

Comment: Please take some time to learn about JOIN types

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN returns matching lines from both tables, if one is empty, the result would always be empty.

You probably want to use

```
SELECT * FROM people LEFT JOIN people_generated on people.id = people_generated.id WHERE people_generated.id_IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The opposite for inner join ?

Comment: Not really an opposite, but you probably want to use LEFT JOIN. I have edited the answer with what you probably need